# Submitting files in webform using POST on Drupal (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have this image and I've used converted it to BitmapData. I have a webform on my localhost drupal website. In the webform I have a file field and a few other text fields. Now the problem is I used a simple `URLVariable` to submit all my text fields like this:

```
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars['submission[data][1][values][0]']= values.text;
```

But I don't know the syntax for submitting the files. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file using AS3, you can use FileReference.upload

look here for an example : [FileReference example (Adobe)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#includeExamplesSummary)

**Edit :**

At the last of adobe's example we have this :

`var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
file.upload(uploadURL);`

So our flash will send the file to `uploadURL`, which is, in our example, a **ColdFusion** script (**.cfm**).

To do that with **php**, for example, take a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php.

Example for using **php** on server side :

**AS3 code** :

```
...
var uploadURL = 'http://your-site/your-php-script.php';
...
var file:FileReference = FileReference(event.target);
file.upload(uploadURL);
```

**PHP code (your-php-script.php)** :

```
<?php

    // set uploads dir
    $uploads_dir = '/uploads_dir';

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $temp_file = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploads_dir;
        $target_file = rtrim($target_path,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

        // move uploaded file from temp dir to target dir
        move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_file);
    }

?>
```

Comment: I've already looked into it , But where do I upload the files to> 
Where do the files get saved after you upload them via a webform submission?